# How to do Targets work for Windows Phone C# project in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

Similarly to Xcode for iOS, projects are built out to a target (as shown below)

[image]

I have a project for Windows Phone and a few copies (Targets), but with different settings (pictures, resources, sounds, etc.)
How something like that to make in Visual Studio? More specifically the project for Windows Phone?
It's really do? Maybe there is an analogue?

Comment: Why not make three different projects?

Comment: In xcode is a normal practice, and how to be in Visual Studio? In Xcode: one project (one code) and a plurality of Target (settings, resources, etc.)
In Visual Studio: ? many projects? a lot of code? support for all of these projects will take more time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more or less an Xcode benefit from my understanding.

I think a good way to get around this would be to make a `GIT` branch of the project and reuse the 'Master-branch' code. This way you would build upon the master branch without duplicating code.

This is approximately what creating another target does.

> In the context of iOS mobile app development, a clone is simply an app that is based off another mobile app. A clone usually has more or less the same code base with probably a slightly different functionality. It’s quite common for this app to have new images, even though most of the UI is the same as the original app.
>
> There are different ways to handle the development of clones. Probably the most common or the one that will first come to mind is using branches.
>
> - iTexico

[xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)